# Edit Distance Similarity in Lucene/Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, similarity

Anyone know if there is any Edit Distance similarity implementation, like [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) in Lucene/Solr? Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you suggesting? Indexing entire protein sequences using a library built for bag of words/vector space representations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [fuzzy queries](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html) and [fuzzy term enumeration](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyTermsEnum.html) use Levenshtein edit distance.

Answer (score 1):

Solr has both Levenstein and Jaro-Winkler as query functions, which means you can sort on them, add them to the returned documents or use them to compute the document score  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#strdist

Comment: Unclear: the word "cand" ... do you mean "can" or "can't"?