# Solr Proximity search

Tags: sorting, search, solr, proximity

I need to implement search results as per the below link..
https://pastebin.com/abuwJxQp

Example 1:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3


    Doc1 Word1
    Doc2 Word 1 Word3
    Doc3 Word 1 Word2 Word3
    Doc4 Word 2 Word 3
    Doc5 Word2 Word1 Word3


    ------------>
        Doc3
        Doc5
        Doc4
        Doc2
        Doc1`
```

Example 2:
    Word1 Word2 Word3
        Doc1 (Title) Word1 Word2 Word3
        Doc2 (Abstract) Word1 Word3 Word3
        Doc3 (AuthorName) Word1 Word2 Word3
        Doc4 (JournalName) Word1 Word2 Word3
        Doc5 (PublisherName) Word1 Word2 Word3

```
    ------------>
        Doc1
        Doc2
        ?
```

Example 3:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3


    Doc1 Word1
    Doc2 Word 1 Word3
    Doc3 Word 1 Word2 Word3
    Doc4 Word 2 Word 3
    Doc5 Word2 Word1 Word3
    Doc6 Word1 Word1 Word1 Word1 Word1 Word1 Word1 Word1 Word1 Word1 Word1 Word1
    Doc7 Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2


    ------------>
        Doc3   
        Doc5
        Doc4
        Doc2
        Doc6?
        Doc1
```

Comment: Why should doc 3 be sorted above doc 5? Doc 3 doesn't contain the same word, unless you mean that "Word 1" is the same as "Word1". You'll have to be exact in your examples here, since these will be mean different things. It'd also be helpful with a description about why you want certain documents prioritized.

Comment: doc 3 has all the words and in the same order as the query. doc 5 has all the words but not in a order. This is the requirement.

Comment: You need to be careful about actually using the same terms here - "word 1" and "word1" will have different meaning depending on the solution. The ComplexPhraseQueryParser with `inOrder=true` as a [boost would probably be a good solution](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser) if I've parsed your question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into "distance" measures - see the answers to this question [Edit Distance Similarity in Lucene/Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607413/edit-distance-similarity-in-lucene-solr)